# React redirect doesn't work. Continue to stay in the same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do a login with laravel react, so when I receive jwt from server I wanna redirect to my main page, but I continue to stay on the same page

```
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';


const Login = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [jwt, setJwt] = useState("");

    const login = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        await axios.post("/login", {
            email: email,
            password: password
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
            if (response.data[0] === "credenziali errate") {
                console.log('credenziali errate')
            } else if (response.data.token) {
                setJwt(response.data.token);
                return (<Route>
                    <Redirect to="/" />
                </Route>)

            }
        });
        setEmail("")
        setPassword("")
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} name="" id="" required/>
            <input type="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} name="" id="" required/>
            <button type="submit" onClick={login}>Login</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning JSX only has an effect when done synchronously, directly in the body of the component. Use the `useNavigate` hook instead.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
// inside component:
const navigate = useNavigate();
// after axios request completes:
navigate('/'); // go to home page
```

Comment: this is the solution, thank you

Comment: @ChristianTermo Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a React Element (...) within a function / promise.

Instead of returning that, call `redirect('/')` see: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect